# Select blocks of time with MaterialDateTimePicker

Tags: java, android, time, kotlin, timepicker

I want to show a clock where only a selected blocks of times can be selected. For example: I want the clock to only let me select times from 09:00 to 10:00 or from 12:00 to 12:30 or from 14:00 to 18:00. All hours outside those ranges should not me selectable.

Using [MaterialDateTimePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#additional-options) I was able to set a array of selected times:

```
val time = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(timeSet, true)
time.setSelectableTimes(arrayOf(Timepoint(10), Timepoint(11)))
```

But this only let me select the time of 10:00 and 11:00 and not the interval between them.

Is it possible to do a behaviour like I explained with this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I decided to create a new method to create an array of TimePoints:

```
private fun getTimes(array: JSONArray): Array<Timepoint> {
    val times = arrayListOf<Timepoint>()
    for (i in 0..array.length().minus(1)) {
        val format = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())

        val start = Calendar.getInstance()
        start.time = format.parse(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("start"))

        val end = Calendar.getInstance()
        end.time = format.parse(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("end"))

        while (!start.after(end)) {
            times.add(Timepoint(start.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), start.get(Calendar.MINUTE)))
            start.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1)
        }
    }

    return times.toArray(arrayOfNulls<Timepoint>(times.size))
}
```

And I would call him like that:

```
time.setSelectableTimes(getTimes(array))
```

**Explanation**:

By using the method:

```
time.setSelectableTimes(arrayOf(Timepoint(10), Timepoint(11)))
```

I would only be enable to choose the times of 10:00h and 11:00h respectively, so the solution is to find all the times between 10:00h and 11:00h and add them to an array. Only then with this new array I can call the method above.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging throught the ["additional options"](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#additional-options) category (the exact one you linked, in fact), and discovered `enableMinutes(true)`. According to the documentation, this defaults to true, so I'm not sure how it became disabled in your code. If you want to enable choosing seconds as well, use `enableSeconds(true)`.

Quote from documentation:

> `TimepickerDialog` `enableSeconds(boolean enableSconds)` and `enableMinutes(boolean enableMinutes)` Allows you to enable or disable a seconds and minutes picker on the `TimepickerDialog`. Enabling the seconds picker, implies enabling the minutes picker. Disabling the minute picker will disable the seconds picker. The last applied setting will be used. By default `enableSeconds = false` and `enableMinutes = true`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this does not solve my problem. This is defaulted to true indeed, the problem is  time.setSelectableTimes(arrayOf(Timepoint(10), Timepoint(11))) only let me choose two times and not the interval between them, even enabling minutes to true.